# Need XAMPP with PHP 5.4 version - windows

Tags: php, windows, xampp, php-5.4

I have come across a situation where I need XAMPP with PHP 5.4 version. I will install it on windows server 2003.

May I know the repository where I can find all the older versions of xampp for windows?

Thanks!

Comment: Just to justify he's question. Xampp offial page does not show the php version when selecting a old version of wamp making it extremely hard when you want a specific version I had to use the following link to find what I wanted http://code.stephenmorley.org/articles/xampp-version-history-apache-mysql-php/

Comment: @LeRoy yes, right you are.

Comment: upvoted, just for note Xampp 1.8.2 is using latest php 5.4

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use this link to search for required version

http://www.oldapps.com/xampp.php

Answer (score 21):

Table with XAMPP version and versions of Apache, MySQL and **PHP**

```
XAMPP   Apache  MySQL   PHP 5   PHP 4
1.8.3   2.4.9   5.6.16  5.5.11  
1.8.2   2.4.9   5.5.36  5.4.27  
1.8.1   2.4.3   5.5.27  5.4.7   
1.8.0   2.4.2   5.5.25a 5.4.4   
1.7.7   2.2.21  5.5.16  5.3.8   
1.7.5   2.2.21  5.5.15  5.3.8   
1.7.4   2.2.17  5.5.8   5.3.5   
1.7.3   2.2.14  5.1.41  5.3.1   
1.7.2   2.2.12  5.1.37  5.3.0   
1.7.1   2.2.11  5.1.33  5.2.9   
1.7.0   2.2.11  5.1.30  5.2.8   
1.6.8   2.2.9   5.0.67  5.2.6   4.4.9
1.6.7   2.2.9   5.0.51b 5.2.6   4.4.8
1.6.6a  2.2.8   5.0.51a 5.2.5   4.4.8
1.6.6   2.2.8   5.0.51  5.2.5   4.4.8 (RC2)
1.6.5   2.2.6   5.0.51  5.2.5   4.4.7
1.6.4   2.2.6   5.0.45  5.2.4   4.4.7
1.6.3a  2.2.4   5.0.45  5.2.3   4.4.7
1.6.3   2.2.4   5.0.54  5.2.3   4.4.7
1.6.2   2.2.4   5.0.41  5.2.2   4.4.7
1.6.1   2.2.4   5.0.37  5.2.1   4.4.6
1.6.0a  2.2.4   5.0.33  5.2.1   4.4.5
1.6.0   2.2.3   5.0.33  5.2.1   4.4.5
```

Download Links:

https://sourceforge.mirrorservice.org/x/xa/xampp/XAMPP%20Windows/
http://www.oldapps.com/xampp.php
https://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/files/XAMPP%20Windows/1.8.0/

Comment: where did you find this info? is there an updated full version?

Comment: he url is not working but i found this site https://www.apachefriends.org/blog/new_xampp_20140822.html

Answer (score 20):

[Click here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/files/XAMPP%20Windows/1.8.0/) to download XAMPP with PHP 5.4 version.

[Click here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/files/) to download older versions of XAMPP from SourceForge.

[Click here](http://code.stephenmorley.org/articles/xampp-version-history-apache-mysql-php/) to find versions of XAMPP, PHP and MySQL.